# On select specific single row showing different result in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12, postgresql-13

Selecting a specific single row showing different result in PostgreSQL which is very strange. There is a table named Employee. When I search like " **SELECT UserId FROM Employee WHERE UserId='3123'**" it shows another results as an output. Its output is like "3135". How UserId could be different?

I am using  3-node pgpool DB cluster in asynchronous replication.  Why does this happen? How can I identify that mismatch? Is there any relation between them?

[image]

Comment: Is `userid` a string data type? Anyway, the only explanation that comes to my mind is data corruption.

Comment: Yes, string type

Comment: I am also thinking about data corruption. Even when trying to backup, at the middle of the backup it exits with an error like "null value in column id which violet the null constraint". This shows a few row is null. Now how can I recover those data? Actually, in the data, there is no null value available but in the backup, it shows a null value in a few rows. I don't understand why in the middle of the backup it shows a few rows' value is null. Now how can I backup?

Comment: If you have a corrupted database, you don't need to backup, you need to *restore* your last good backup.

Comment: Unable to restore from previous backup, now show this error at pg_dump "pg_dump: error: Error message from server: ERROR:  invalid memory alloc request size 18446744073709551613"

Comment: You restore with `pg_restore`, not with `pg_dump`. You clearly have data corruption, and you are not telling us any details. So you are on your own.

Comment: sorry, it was solve by removing those rows. I thought it was solved but few days later I found another issue is that duplicate data mismatch at primary and standby. Example: At primary, at Employee table one username but at standby two username of same user. How it is possible at standby? It should be same. After 5-10 test I realized that only solution ,take a successful backup with enabling zero_damaged_pages and restore it. Till now working fine. Lets see what comes next. Do you think is it right approach? Waiting for your comments.